# Check if m3u8 has a stream c#

Tags: c#, m3u8

I'm building a desktop application to check if m3u8 files are valid and have a stream. I tried to include VLC Lib in my project but I had a run time error and I could not include it,then I tried flash object but it did not play m3u8 file.Please advice and thank you.

Comment: The format is very simple so it doesn't take many lines of code to check what is in a m3u8 file. Depending on your definition of valid or "has a stream" it most likely doesn't need any libraries. Could you expand on those requirements? Do you need to check the actual media files for existence, are they broken etc also?

Comment: I want to play the m3u8 files one by one through my code and check if each file is playing something or giving an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these projects for playing m3u8 files [WPF-MediaKit](https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit) and [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet).
Now I'm using WPF-MediaKit, although it's redundant to just play m3u8 files.